# What is the difference between חיי העולם הבא and חיי העולמים (in Bircas Hamazon)?

Tags: ashkenazi, bentching, olam-haba-world-to-come

Towards the end of Bircas Hamazon on Shabbos, Ashenazim say 
הרחמן הוא ינחילנו יום שכולו שבת ומנוחה לחיי העולמים

Later and every day they say,
הרחמן הוא  יזכנו לימות המשיח ולחיי העולם הבא

What is the difference between חיי העולם הבא and חיי העולמים?

Comment: we? I don't know that Sefardim have that Harachaman for Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA Quite right. I'll learn one day iy"H. Edited Q.

Comment: What is worth noting is that even Teimanim have the nusach of לחיי העולם הבא in regards to Mashiach.

Answer (score 2):

חיי העולמים - usually refers to this world AND the world to come.

חיי העולם הבא - refers only to the world to come.

We are asking for two separate things, hence the difference in terms used:

The first one is asking for rest and tranquility in this world and the world to come.

The second one is asking for us to merit the coming of Moshiach and the world to come.

Comment: what is you source?